# Create database only at installation time in phonegap android app

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, local-storage

I'm new in phonegap android application. (Sorry for my poor english.)

I want to create a simple app which has a searching pages for fill user details. I'm using web service for get user's relational details. On a field i want to search some type of static code from database. we decide to store them in local database instead of server so that search process will be fast. I've some problem to create database. I want to create one time database only when app install. 
i used following code.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
        }
        function populateDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
        }

        // Query the database

        function queryDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
        }

        // Query the success callback

        function querySuccess(tx, results) {
            // console.log("Returned rows = " + results.rows.length);
            var len = results.rows.length;
            console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
            }
            // this will be true since it was a select statement and so rowsAffected was 0
            if (!results.rowsAffected) {
                console.log('No rows affected!');
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Transaction error callback
        function errorCB(err) {
            console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
        }

        // Transaction success callback

        function successCB() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
        }
```

All data are on server in mySQL database. I want to store them in demo table in local database in app when it install on the device.

I've following problems-

1. Database is overwriting demo table's rows every time when it run in device.
2. Demo table have approximate 15000 rows in mysql database. i can take a mysql database table backup but how to restore that in app database.
3. Can i call a webservice to store all data on installation time.
4. Same question if i'm using to localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Use sqllite or local storage...
http://www.sqlite.org/